# sqlalchemy bulk_update fail

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

my table user_info as follow:

```
class UserInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_info'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    user_code = Column(CHAR(16), nullable=False, comment='工号')
    goal_1 = Column(CHAR(16))
    goal_2 = Column(CHAR(16))
    prem_1 = Column(CHAR(16))
    prem_2 = Column(CHAR(16))
```

It has about 10k datas and all of the columns 'goal' and 'prem' are NULL,
I want to update these columns with random data,
for test I just update 50 rows and my code as follow:

```
    def insert_prem_date(self, count=50):
        users = self.db.session.query(UserInfo).limit(count)

        user_codes = [i.user_code for i in users]
        print(user_codes)

        prem_list = []
        for _code in user_codes:
            prem_list.append(
                {"user_code": _code,
                 "prem_1": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 "prem_2": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 "goal_1": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 "goal_2": str(random.randint(500, 500000))
                 }
            )
        self.db.session.bulk_update_mappings(
            UserInfo,
            prem_list
        )

        self.db.session.commit()
```

And the was ERROR:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANWb2.png)
I am sure that the `user_code` are exist in the table

**so how can i update it correctly?**

I also try this code but **it doesn't work**: **not ERROR** but also **not update data** in table

```
        for _code in user_codes:
            prem_list.append(
                {UserInfo.user_code: _code,
                 UserInfo.prem_1: str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 UserInfo.prem_2: str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 UserInfo.goal_1: str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
                 UserInfo.goal_2: str(random.randint(500, 500000))
                 }
            )
```

Comment: Try using `id` instead of `user_code`

Comment: thanks for your answer and it is works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's a misunderstanding in how `bulk_update_mappings` works.

It is impossible to use `bulk_update_mappings` by field(your unique field) which is different than `primary key`.

Your mapping dictionary doesn't contain `primary key`.
Passing with a list of parameter dictionaries with a full primary key value will invoke `bulk UPDATE by primary key mode` for statement, generating the `WHERE` criteria to match each row by `primary key` and using executemany.

Approach to use bulk_update_mappings

```py
def insert_prem_date(self, count=50):
   # Fetch users
   users = self.db.session.query(UserInfo).limit(count)

   # Extract user IDs
   user_ids = [user.id for user in users]
   print(user_ids)

   # Generate random data for each column and prepare for bulk update
   prem_list = [
       {
           "id": user_id,
           "prem_1": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
           "prem_2": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
           "goal_1": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
           "goal_2": str(random.randint(500, 500000)),
       }
       for user_id in user_ids
   ]

   # Perform bulk update
   self.db.session.bulk_update_mappings(
       UserInfo,
       prem_list
   )

   # Commit the changes
   self.db.session.commit()
```

Original method without bulk_update

```py
def update_prem_data(self, count=50):
    users = self.db.session.query(UserInfo).limit(count).all()

    for user in users:
        user.prem_1 = str(random.randint(500, 500000))
        user.prem_2 = str(random.randint(500, 500000))
        user.goal_1 = str(random.randint(500, 500000))
        user.goal_2 = str(random.randint(500, 500000))

    self.db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and it is works,  and i just checked my code and discovered that the mistake was due to I had alter the table structure, by changing the primary key from column `id` to the `user_code` but forgot to update the view model class UserInfo. so i use the primary key incorrect.